# oracle streams - how to get last successfully applied scn for crashed apply?

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-streams

I have a downstream Streams replication set up between Oracle 9i (source) and Oracle 11g (destination). The process is still in developlment stage, so the whole setup is not stable yet.

Sometimes my apply procedure at destination database fails. Say, with a error like this:

```
APPLY_NAME                     STATUS   RULE_SET_NAME                  ERROR_MESSAGE
------------------------------ -------- ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
DWH_APPLY_SUN                  ABORTED  RULESET_APPLY_LCR_SUN          ORA-26808: Apply process AS0K died unexp
                                                                       ectedly.
                                                                       ORA-25455: evaluation error for rule set
                                                                       : STRMADMIN.RULESET_APPLY_LCR_SUN, evalu
                                                                       ation context: SYS.STREAMS$_EVALUATION_C
                                                                       ONTEXT
                                                                       ORA-00600: internal error code, argument
                                                                       s: [knlqany2lcr235], [22629], [ORA-22629
                                                                       : OCIAnyData is null
                                                                       ], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I need to know the last source database SCN it was able to apply before failing.

`DBA_APPLY.MAX_APPLIED_MESSAGE_NUMBER` shows me something only in case apply process is stopped normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

> Low-Watermark and High-Watermark for an Apply Process
>
> The low-watermark for an apply process is the system change number
>   (SCN) up to which all LCRs have been applied. That is, LCRs that were
>   committed at an SCN less than or equal to the low-watermark number
>   have definitely been applied, but some LCRs that were committed with a
>   higher SCN also might have been applied. The low-watermark SCN for an
>   apply process is equivalent to the applied SCN for a capture process.
>
> The high-watermark for an apply process is the SCN beyond which no
>   LCRs have been applied. That is, no LCRs that were committed with an
>   SCN greater than the high-watermark have been applied.
>
> You can view the low-watermark and high-watermark for one or more
>   apply processes by querying the V$STREAMS_APPLY_COORDINATOR and
>   ALL_APPLY_ PROGRESS data dictionary views.